# JPA2 NullPointerException when saving entities with @OneToMany relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa-2.0, one-to-many

I have two entities with `@OneToMany` relationship.  Problem is I get a null pointer on the line `getComps().add(comp)` during save.  It works fine if I explicitly instantiate the `comps` set. As you may know, this is not required if you have the annotations. I have other objects in that entity which work fine without explicit instantiation. What are the possible causes?

```
//Main Method    
public static void main(String argz[]){
  ....
  Message message = new Message();
  message.setMessage("Hello World!");
  Comp comp = new Comp();
  comp.setName(getName());
  message.addComp(comp);
  user.createMessage(message);
  User aUser =  userService.save(user);
}

//Message Entity
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(targetEntity = Comp.class,
                mappedBy="message",
                fetch=FetchType.LAZY, 
                cascade={CascadeType.All},
                orphanRemoval=true)
private Set<Comp> comps;

public void addComp(Comp comp){
    comp.setMessage(this);
    getComps().add(comp);
}

//Comp Entity       
@JsonIgnore
@JsonBackReference
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name="message_id")
private Message message;
```

Comment: Show us the code you're executing. Your expectations are probably wrong.

Comment: I've included the tester method that I am using for test. see above

Comment: There's no need to be familiar with Hibernate to answer such a question. You're instantiating a Message whose set of comps is null, and you're then trying to add a Comp to this set. Hibernate doesn't have anything to do with your error. You can't call a method on a null reference, that's all. You should accept Roman's answer.

Comment: Have a look at the line "private Collection orders;" do you see instantiation? tinyurl.com/kom3hfr

Comment: No. So what? Hibernate is not black voodoo. Having it in the classpath won't allow you to call methods on null references. In the article you linked to, do you see any place where the collection of orders is accessed after having instantiating a Customer using new? Do you realize that Hibernate can't magically initialize fields of objects it doesn't create? For the record, I have answered 1462 Hibernate questions here with a score of 2031. Don't you think I know what I'm talking about?

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the exception is in the code

```
private Set<Comp> comps;
```

change to

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "message")
private Set<Comp> comps = new HashSet<Comp>(0);

public Set<Comp> getComps() {
  return this.comps;
}

public void setComps(Set<Comp> comps) {
  this.comps = comps;
}
```